# Why I can't install proprietary drivers?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am following [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) for installing Bumblebee on my Dell n5110 but I am getting this error when I reach the fourth step of the tutorial. What am I doing wrong or what else do I need to do?

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      bumblebee-nvidia : Depends: nvidia-driver but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-glx but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-kernel-dkms but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-kernel-amd64 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-kernel-686-pae but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-kernel-486 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-current but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-current-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-driver-binary but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-304 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-304-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-experimental-304 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-310 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-310-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-experimental-310 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-313 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-313-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-experimental-313 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-319 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-319-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-experimental-319 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-325 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-325-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-experimental-325 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-331 but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-331-updates but it is not installable or
                         nvidia-experimental-331 but it is not installable
              E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to the "Software and Updates" program.
2. On the "Ubuntu Software" tab, under **Downloadable from the Internet**, ensure that the "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" source is checked. You will have to authenticate with your password.
3. Close "Software and Updates". You will have to reload the package information or run `sudo apt-get update` again. Proceed with the procedure in the guide.

Comment: Is there an equivalent from the command line?

Comment: You may use `nano` to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment any lines ending in `restricted`.